# BitBlt - более быстрый аналог

Tags: c++, winapi

Реализую запись видео с экрана. Требуемый fps - не ниже 50.
К сожалению, с использованием `BitBlt` такого результата не достичь (20 ms на все "телодвижения", у меня выполняется за 30-40 ms).

Я, конечно, понимаю, что эта функция годы проходила оптимизацию, выполняется практически самим драйвером устройства (ну, как я прочитал в одном из обсуждений подобного вопроса на другом ресурсе), но реально нужно что-то побыстрее. Желательно без сторонних библиотек конечно же.

```
BITMAP GetScreenshort()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    HBITMAP hbtmScreen;
    BITMAP bmp;

    HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC hdcCompatible = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
    int height = GetDeviceCaps(hdcScreen, VERTRES);
    int width = GetDeviceCaps(hdcScreen, HORZRES);

    hbtmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, width, height);
    SelectObject(hdcCompatible, hbtmScreen);
    BitBlt(hdcCompatible, 0, 0, width, height, hdcScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    CURSORINFO cinfo;
    ZeroMemory(&cinfo, sizeof(CURSORINFO));
    cinfo.cbSize = sizeof(CURSORINFO);
    GetCursorInfo(&cinfo);

    DrawIconEx(hdcCompatible, cinfo.ptScreenPos.x, cinfo.ptScreenPos.y, cinfo.hCursor, 0, 0, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);

    GetObject(hbtmScreen, sizeof BITMAP, &bmp);

    DeleteDC(hdcScreen);
    DeleteDC(hdcCompatible);

    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(finish - start).count() << std::endl;

    return bmp;
}
```

**UPD:** Как самое быстрое решение для версий Windows >=8, предпочту Desktop Dusplication API. Конкретный пример использования - [Использование Desktop Duplication API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704154/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-desktop-duplication-api).

Comment: А у Вас сколько мониторов подключено, и какой смысл брать в качестве источника `CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", L"", L"", NULL)`, может достаточно `GetDC(NULL)`? Ну и освобождения `DC` в коде не видно. А для замеров мремени лучше использовать `<chrono>`.

Comment: Между `GetDC` и `CreateDC` есть разница в данном случае? Освобождение действительно отсутствует (сейчас добавлю). Вот ещё решил заменить `HBITMAP` на `BITMAP` (всё равно в итоге эта операция выполняется). Не могли бы вы ещё подсказать вот ещё под какому текущему вопросу: как получить управляемый объект `Bitmap` из неуправляемого `BITMAP`, который возвращает эта функция (это библиотечная функция для C# приложения).

Comment: Согласно новым замерам функция выполняется в среднем за 40 ms (вывод в микросекундах, я ничего не напутал :)

Comment: Подключён один монитор, но буду делать поддержку нескольких (т.е. выбор).

Comment: А вы можете несколько потоков использовать?

Comment: А вы как думаете?

Comment: Ох как я люблю такие вопросы. Вы о чем то человека спрашиваете, а он перенаправляет вопрос на вас, заставляя считать себя дураком. Проблема в том что это работает только 1 раз, а потом ничего кроме ненависти к тому у кого спрашиваешь не вызывает.

Comment: Ничего подобного я ввиду не имел. Все действия в функции выполняются последовательно и, как мне кажется, в отдельный поток вынести просто нечего (тем более, что все остальные функции, кроме `GetObject` и `BitBlt`, выполняются меньше миллисекунды). Скорость выполнения `GetObject` меня устраивает. А вот `BitBlt`, как уже говорил, выполняется у меня более 30 мс, что непозволительно для мои задач. Вот я и спрашиваю, неужели вы знаете как это распараллелить...

Comment: `CreateDC` создает девайс со всеми мониторами (слева-направо), `GetDC` - только с первичным. Из `DC` напрямую не получить управляемый объект.

Comment: Кстати, fpc выше 25 не имеет особого смысла. Визуально Вы эту разницу просто не уловите.

Comment: На моём компьютере 25, на другом будет 15. Да и повыпендриваться перед пользователем вообще то. Но скорее первое, чем второе.

Comment: "Как самое быстрое решение для версий Windows >=8, предпочту Desktop Duplication" -- пока пример не рабочий, о его скорости говорить преждевременно

Comment: Ну это да)) Только ответ то будет. Если не чей-то другой, так мой. Пока да, код не рабочий. Но ссылку то, кстати, на рабочий исходник вы оставили в ответе.

Comment: @mega Если честно, это была реклама. Премию назначу через 2 часа.

Comment: @mega А почему о скорости говорить преждевременно? Это специализированный набор API функций, так что не знаю не знаю...

Comment: Преждевременно, потому что скриншоты пример не делает, т.е. по факту - не копирует данные из одной памяти в другую, т.е. не совершает работу, которую мы оцениваем. Ссылку - да оставил, и время тоже зафиксировал - безуспешную попытку (у меня 2 таких варианта), но, в итоговом рейтинге этот пример пока не принимает участие. Надеюсь, интрига разрешится.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для более точной картины, Вам надо делать не единичный замер скорости, а усредненный замер на серии экспериментов.

Например, можно вынести код замеров в отдельный поток, в котором бесконечно вызывать `BitBlt`. Но, думаю, Вы будете замерять по сути скорость работы Ваших модулей RAM.

Скорость работы `BitBlt` будет зависеть от формата и разрешения картинки, которую Вы таким образом копируете. Вот к примеру у меня `1920x1080`, 32bit, т.е. **`8Мб` на каждый растр**. Учитывая пиковую скорость моей RAM (PC3-14200) копирование 8мб займет `563мкс`, в идеальных условиях, конечно же.

Вот тут человек делал аналогичные замеры: [How to make BitBlt faster (for copying screen)?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/2cbe4674-e744-41d6-bc61-3c8e381aa942/how-to-make-bitblt-faster-for-copying-screen?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment). И у него выходило `4-20мс`. Опять же, это зависит от многих факторов.

Т.е., когда Вы пишете: "Требуемый fps - не ниже 50", учитывайте еще разрешение, глубину цвета, скорость Вашей RAM. Вполне возможно, что Вас устроит какой-то компромисс между всеми этими зависимостями.

А вот и пример: https://pastebin.com/qWYKVtFr
Здесь время загрузки кадра равно `32.38ms`, т.е. `30,9fps`, причем, за это время не просто снимается скрин, он еще и пишется в `*.avi`. На самом деле, это пример из 5го варианта (см. ниже), только тут **размер скрина `100x100`**. А если отключить запись в avi, то этот же пример покажет уже `18.7ms`, т.е. **`53,5fps`**.

---

Для сравнения, я посмотрел другие варианты. И вот какие результаты получил:

1. DirectX, как уже сообщил @D.Stark, показал скорость **`~40ms`** на кадр. У меня примерно такая же скорость (его же код: https://pastebin.com/VRrFy3DH)
2. WMEncoder - при запуске энкодера (`IWMEncoder::Start`) - возвращает ошибку `E_NOIMPL`. В источнике по [ссылке с проектом](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen) есть аналогичная проблема у человека. Ему посоветовали убедиться, что установлен сам [Windows Media Encoder](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj7s5ymkbDVAhWmYJoKHYSxARoQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2F%3FLinkId%3D67406&usg=AFQjCNGV7lx73jZWiIRgWG24S3XltY1F8A), у меня он стоит. Возможно нужно поперебирать версии. Кстати, этот вариант требует [Windows Media Encoder SDK](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/SDK-DDK/Windows-Media-Encoder-SDK.shtml). И следует собирать `x64`-проект, если установлен `x64 Windows Media Encoder`.
3. [Microsoft Expression Encoder 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27870) - аналогичный проект, на замену WMEncoder. Правда у него примеры на C#. Здесь скорость **`~70ms`** на кадр (но он сразу пишет видео в формате `*.xesc`). Мой немного скорректированный [ScreenCapture sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724706(v=expression.40).aspx) на C#: https://pastebin.com/gAvmgwUa
4. `Windows Desktop Duplication API` - показывает очень хорошую производительность **`~7-14ms`**, но смущает то, что у меня получились пустые скриншоты на `WinServ2012R2 Standard`. Пока считаю, что проблема в том, что у меня сервер запущен на `vmware`. Рабочий исходник от @D.Stark: https://pastebin.com/qyYMNP3G
5. Для полной картины, мой усредненный вариант `BitBlt` показывает **`~36-38ms`**: https://pastebin.com/E8mwEgzV. Для сравнения этого варианта с `Microsoft Expression Encoder 4` (вариант 3), я добавил сюда код для формирования `avi`, и получил уже **`~138ms`** на фрейм: https://pastebin.com/Dwid4wfs. Для работы с `avi` я использовал легкие врапперы от [Lucian Wischik](http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/avi_utils.html).
    
   Вынес из `AddAviFrame` вызов `GetObject` - сократил время на фрейм до **`128ms`**: https://pastebin.com/a9ZiEzC5. Затем - перенес avi на `SSD` и получил уже **`68.17ms`** на фрейм: https://pastebin.com/R30NpzhJ. Еще раз посмотрел на 3й вариант и выяснил, что он тоже генерил свой `*.xesc` на SSD, т.е., выходит, что 5й вариант немного быстрее третьего. Скорее всего, это связано с компрессией, которую делает `Microsoft Expression Encoder` и в одинаковых условиях тесты дадут одинаковый результат.

---

В общем, в моем рейтинге пока лидирует 5й - `BitBlt` и 3й - `Microsoft Expression Encoder 4` варианты.

p.s.: еще раз хочу заметить, что все замеры здесь субъективны относительно моих вычислительных мощностей. Гарантию даю только на то, что все варианты запускались в одних условиях (кроме 4, у которого особые требования к OS).

Comment: Компромисс между значениями? Мне же не дано что-то изменить. Только замерить.

Comment: Так же вы хотите сказать, что более быстрых аналогов не существует?

Comment: "Мне же не дано что-то изменить." -- почему же? Вам ни кто не мешает снимать растр `100x100`, а не `HORZRESxVERTRES`, например. Полезного конечно мало, но зато можно почувствовать существенную разницу в fps.

Comment: "Так же вы хотите сказать, что более быстрых аналогов не существует?" -- есть конечно бесспорный аналог - вообще не копировать растр в RAM, а все что надо от него - делать непосредственно в видеопамяти. Шейдеры, например, этим как раз и выигрывают по производительности. К тому же, Вы хотите делать видео, т.е. так или иначе - придется сохранять растр в RAM.

Comment: Посмотрите еще проект [Various methods for capturing the screen](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen). Тут используются методы DirectX и Windows Media API для копирования растра. Ну и конечно, аппаратное ускорение у Вас должно быть включено.

Comment: А что я могу использовать для проверки и включения аппаратного ускорения?

Comment: А вот ссылку, я думаю, вас следует включить в ответ.

Comment: Вот ещё один интересующий меня вопрос, если вам не сложно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696725/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0

Comment: @D.Stark, а мне было бы интересно посмотреть на результаты DirectX и Windows Media API. Вы не пробовали еще, может оформите ответ, если эти методы решают задачу быстрее?

Comment: "для проверки и включения аппаратного ускорения?" -- думаю, это отдельный вопрос, тут специфика DirectX - gamedev. Вот, к примеру -
 исходники какого-то рендера, тут много разных Acceleration: [video_render_windows_impl.cc](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/8334751/), но не знаю, насколько они актуальны сегодня, возможно есть способы проще.

Comment: Я пока что не преступал к тестированию. Скорее всего займусь этим завтра/послезавтра, ну а о результатах я конечно же здесь отпишусь)

Comment: Протестировал работу с DirectX (Windows 10, DirectX 12, аппаратное ускорение включено) и у меня получается в среднем 40 мс: https://pastebin.com/VRrFy3DH (код сохранения скриншота убрал, но он успешен - всё работает корректно; замеры проводил конечно же без сохранения изображения в файл). Т.е. ещё хуже :(

Comment: А вот по-поводу Windows Media API - понять не могу где найти `IWMEncoder2`. На MSDN документацию об этом интерфейсе я не нашёл, в исходниках на CodeProject по вашей ссылке используется `wmencode.h`, который у меня не подключается. Мне нужно устанавливать WM Encoder SDK что ли? Что за ерунда?

Comment: Да и к тому же, это же вроде далеко не на всех версиях Windows поддерживается? Разве нет?

Comment: Ещё, как вариант, нашёл такое решение: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/hh404487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (доступно с Windows 8).

Comment: Поправьте, пожалуйста, мой грубо слепленный код: https://pastebin.com/qyYMNP3G. Это работа с Windows Desktop Duplication API. Работает, но как вычленить отсюда код ответственный за новый фрейм я что-то не догоняю (как и обязанность волочить `CComPtrCustom`) (с COM совсем почти раньше не работал). Со всей инициализацией объектов пока что получается в среднем 140 мс (с вызова `AcquireNextFrame` до сохранения в файл проходит 10-15 мс).

Comment: Посмотрел код для `Windows Desktop Duplication API` - да, достаточно быстро снимает скриншоты (на `WinServ2012R2 Standard` 8-14ms), но все они пустые почему-то (черный "квадрат" Малевича). `CComPtrCustom` таскать конечно не обязательно, в `<atlbase.h>` есть для него стандартная замена - `CComPtr`. Как разберусь, откуда проблемы со скриншотами - обновлю ответ.

Comment: Я представил вам полностью рабочий код по `Duplication API`. Там никаких чёрных квадратов нет. Так же, я сразу пробовал заменять `CComPtrCustom` на `CComPtr`, и ничего кроме ошибок после запуска не выходило. Надеюсь, у вас получится более грамотно всё решить.

Comment: Если честно, я не хотел бы делать упор именно на `Windows Desktop Duplication API`. Это можно применять только на Window 8 и >. Конечно, на доступных платформах это сгодится как лучшее решение, но а как же остальные версии Windows? Какие решения можно использовать? Предлагаю вам так же посмотреть мой код по работе с DirectX - всё ли выполняется так быстро, как только можно; и так же снова задуматься о работе с `Windows Media API`, т.к. у меня что-то не получилось найти решение в сети.

Comment: Уточню на всякий случай: рабочий код скриншота с использованием `Desktop Duplication API` мне тоже нужен. Я лишь спрашивал про другие Windows.

Comment: Я смотрел Ваш код с DirectX, там можно только вынести распределение буфера из цикла, но это практически не влияет на скорость. Возможно, есть способ создать к примеру 16битный девайс и снимать с него скриншоты (у меня не получилось), т.е. за счет уменьшения глубины цвета - уменьшить размер растра, и, соответственно - увеличить скорость. Касательно `Windows Desktop Duplication API`, я запускал Ваш вариант на виртуалке (vmware), скорее всего в этом дело, т.к. код сохранения растра верный, он работает с DirectX (посмотрю на "живой" win8).

Comment: Ну как, посмотрели на живой Windows 8? Кстати, мой код по работе с Desktop Duplication API никак нельзя назвать завершённым) Да, он рабочий, но получить 2 скриншота не проводя каждый раз инициализации всего и вся у меня так и не получилось. Надо найти тот самый участок, который отвечает именно за скриншот, и его зациклить для получения нужного количества скриншотов. У вас имеются идеи как это сделать?

Comment: Я думаю, что в итоге использовать `WMEncoder` (т.е., как раз Windows Media API) я не буду. Нужно и SDK качать и подстраиваться под 64-битную версию. При желании это, конечно, не проблема, но и желания с этим работать нет, раз мы не получим лучшего результата, чем имеем уже сейчас.

Comment: Сделаем так: сейчас подработаем мой исходник по Duplication API и я буду использовать именно его на Windows 8/8.1/10 (протестирую, конечно), а `BitBlt` - на более ранних версиях ОС. Да и ведь, по сути, на главный вопрос пока ответа не найдено: Найти более быстрый аналог `BitBlt` (среди функций я думал будем искать). Ничего быстрее Desktop Duplication API мы вряд ли найдём, но а как же другие версии Windows? Оставим им `BitBlt`?.. Всё таки я считаю, что мы не нашли ответа на этот вопрос!

Comment: Но вам уже могу сказать спасибо за содержательный ответ. Это полезная информация, которая может пригодится и при других целях.

Comment: Да, проверил: на win8 "черные" скриншоты. Вот Ваш код, который я немного подправил, чтобы он собирался: https://pastebin.com/jFX15nYv. Вот собранный exe, на котором я проверял: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqm5uqiocl2nljk/696441.exe?dl=0 Кстати, он на win8 показывал более скромные результаты - порядка `20ms`. Возможно, нужно что-то включить в OS, чтобы этот вариант у всех работал. Дайте знать, если найдете решение.

Comment: Честно говоря, мне больше понравился результат у `Microsoft Expression Encoder 4`, т.к. он сразу готовит видео-файл. Думаю, чтобы реально сравнить его с `BitBlt`, надо аналогично собрать растры по крайней мере в avi (поток неупакованных растров).

Comment: Добавил в ответ результаты с формированием `avi`. По моему, для оптимизации `AddAviFrame`, тут можно только вынести `GetObject`. Еще можно добавлять кадры сразу пачкой (по 100 штук, например за раз), а не каждый кадр по отдельности.

Comment: Мне просто не нужна запись видео. Я снимаю картинку с экрана и передаю на удалённый компьютер. Ну как бы это и есть запись экрана. Важно именно отдельный фрейм получить)

Comment: Вы каждый кадр передаете по сети? Уверены, что не хотите задействовать сжатие? Представьте: каждый кадр - `8mb`. `25fps` - это по кадру каждые `40ms`, т.е. 125 кадров на 5сек, т.е. `1000мб` нужно прокачать по сети за время, не более 5сек, т.е. Вам для этого потребуется скорость **`1600мбит/c`**. Посмотрите чего-нить по [сжатию видео](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE), тут используются разные алгоритмы, причем сжимаются не только отдельные кадры, но и совокупность кадров, т.е. сжатое видео прокачивать в сеть гораздо выгоднее.

Comment: Сжатие будет. Так же я не собираюсь полностью передавать изображения - буду нарезать на кусочки и сверять с предыдущим скрином; те, что отличаются будут отправляться. Вся проверка будет выполняться в отдельном потоке для каждого кусочка (ради скорости). + будет не одно соединение: разрубим на 3-5 частей передаваемые данные (если они больше N КБ), и передадим по отдельным соединениям, скорость каждого из которых нас особо не волнует)

Comment: Вон сколько всяких действий. И при этом fps нужен больше 25. Я же говорю: у меня 25, а в других условиях будет 15 - надо с запасом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63398/discussion-between-mega-and-d-stark).