# Получение полного имени устройства аудиозахвата

Tags: c#, windows, directshow

```
ICreateDevEnum devEnum;
IEnumMoniker enumMoniker;
IMoniker[] monikers = new IMoniker[1];
IPropertyBag propBag;

devEnum = (ICreateDevEnum)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum));
devEnum.CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory, out enumMoniker, 0);

while (enumMoniker.Next(1, monikers, IntPtr.Zero) == 0) {

    object variant;
    object propBagObj;

    monikers[0].BindToStorage(null, null, ref IPropertyBagGuid, out propBagObj);
    propBag = (IPropertyBag)propBagObj;

    if (propBag.Read("FriendlyName", out variant, null) == 0)
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(variant.ToString() + " (" + variant.ToString().Length + ")");
}
```

Под Windows 10 этот код у меня работает прекрасно и выводит полное имя микрофона (44 символа). На Windows 7 имя выводится не полное, а лишь первые 31 символ.

Подскажите, что может быть причиной такого поведения и как это починить (возможно, аналогичный более универсальный код)?

На устройствах, сразу скажу, стоят разные версии DirectX (12 (где всё работает) и 11).

Comment: Я б попробовал через IPropertyBag2 посмотреть, что там за свойства вообще есть, и какие у них значения. А вообще — если не выводится, ну и фиг с ним. Не будут же два устройства отличаться только 42-м в символе. Выглядит не слишком гламурно, но влияет только на отображение, не на функциональность.

Comment: `IPropertyBag2`? Вы не опечатались? Да в общем то это не имеет значения. Я и так знаю какие там свойства: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd377566(v=vs.85).aspx. Думаю, в любом случае, где-то будет отображаться так. Но давайте уменьшим количество таких случаев)

Comment: А не попробывали даунгрейд или апгрейд соответсвующих DirectX-ов, для проверки?

Comment: Нет. Что получим как результат? Узнаем, зависит ли это дело от версии DirectX?

Comment: Да - исключим 1 из возможных факторов

Comment: Вы COM-интерфейсы декларируете сами, или используете генерированные Interop Assamblies?

Comment: Возможно это как-то связано с тем, что в структуре WAVEINCAPS поле szPname имеет размер 32 байта. Т.е. В Win7 получение имени устройства идет через эту структуру, а в Win10 - другим путем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать это через Multimedia API. У меня нормально выводит FriendlyName больше 40 символов.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace com_test
{
    /*Объявления COM-интерфейсов*/
    class Native    {

        public static PROPERTYKEY PKEY_Device_FriendlyName = new PROPERTYKEY(0xa45c254e, 0xdf1c, 0x4efd, 0x80, 0x20, 0x67, 0xd1, 0x46, 0xa8, 0x50, 0xe0, 14);

        public static PROPERTYKEY PKEY_AudioEndpoint_FormFactor = 
            new PROPERTYKEY(0x1da5d803, 0xd492, 0x4edd, 0x8c, 0x23, 0xe0, 0xc0, 0xff, 0xee, 0x7f, 0x0e, 0);

    }

    //http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Windows/SoundUtils.htm
    [Guid("0BD7A1BE-7A1A-44DB-8397-CC5392387B5E"),
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IMMDeviceCollection
    {

        //HRESULT GetCount([out, annotation("__out")] UINT* pcDevices);

        int GetCount(ref uint pcDevices);

        //HRESULT Item([in, annotation("__in")]UINT nDevice, [out, annotation("__out")] IMMDevice** ppDevice);

        int Item(uint nDevice, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppDevice);

    }

    [Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IMMDevice
    {

        //HRESULT Activate([in, annotation("__in")] REFIID iid, [in, annotation("__in")] DWORD dwClsCtx, [in,unique, annotation("__in_opt")] PROPVARIANT* pActivationParams, [out,iid_is(iid), annotation("__out")] void** ppInterface);

        int Activate(ref Guid iid, uint dwClsCtx, IntPtr pActivationParams, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppInterface);

        //HRESULT OpenPropertyStore([in, annotation("__in")] DWORD stgmAccess, [out, annotation("__out")] IPropertyStore** ppProperties);

        int OpenPropertyStore(int stgmAccess, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppProperties);

        //HRESULT GetId([out,annotation("__deref_out")] LPWSTR* ppstrId);

        int GetId(ref StringBuilder ppstrId);

        //HRESULT GetState([out, annotation("__out")] DWORD* pdwState);

        int GetState(ref int pdwState);

    }

    [ComImport, Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
    class MMDeviceEnumerator
    {
    }

    [Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"),
    //[Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
    {

        //HRESULT EnumAudioEndpoints([in, annotation("__in")] EDataFlow dataFlow, [in, annotation("__in")] DWORD dwStateMask, [out, annotation("__out")] IMMDeviceCollection** ppDevices);

         int EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow dataFlow, int dwStateMask, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppDevices);

        //HRESULT GetDefaultAudioEndpoint([in, annotation("__in")] EDataFlow dataFlow, [in, annotation("__in")] ERole role, [out, annotation("__out")] IMMDevice** ppEndpoint);

         int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppEndpoint);

        //HRESULT GetDevice([, annotation("__in")]LPCWSTR pwstrId, [out, annotation("__out")] IMMDevice** ppDevice);

         int  GetDevice(string pwstrId, ref IntPtr ppDevice);

        //HRESULT RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback([in, annotation("__in")] IMMNotificationClient* pClient);

         int  RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(IntPtr pClient);

        //HRESULT UnregisterEndpointNotificationCallback([in, annotation("__in")] IMMNotificationClient* pClient);

         int  UnregisterEndpointNotificationCallback(IntPtr pClient);

    }

    public enum EDataFlow
    {
        eRender,
        eCapture,
        eAll,
        EDataFlow_enum_count

    }

    public enum ERole
    {
        eConsole,
        eMultimedia,
        eCommunications,
        ERole_enum_count
    }

    //*********** Property store *****************************

    [ComImport, Guid("886D8EEB-8CF2-4446-8D02-CDBA1DBDCF99"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IPropertyStore
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetCount([Out] out uint cProps);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetAt([In] uint iProp, out PROPERTYKEY pkey);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        int GetValue([In] ref PROPERTYKEY key, out PropVariant pv);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetValue([In] ref PROPERTYKEY key, [In] ref object pv);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Commit();
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    struct PROPERTYKEY
    {
        public Guid fmtid;
        public uint pid;

        public PROPERTYKEY(Guid guid, int propertyId)
    {
        this.fmtid = guid;
        this.pid = (uint)propertyId;
    }
    public PROPERTYKEY(string formatId, int propertyId)
        : this(new Guid(formatId), propertyId)
    {
    }
    public PROPERTYKEY(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f, uint g, uint h, uint i, uint j, uint k, int propertyId)
        : this(new Guid((uint)a, (ushort)b, (ushort)c, (byte)d, (byte)e, (byte)f, (byte)g, (byte)h, (byte)i, (byte)j, (byte)k), propertyId)
    {
    }
    }

    //https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adamroot/2008/04/11/interop-with-propvariants-in-net/

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PropVariant
    {
        ushort vt;
        ushort wReserved1;
        ushort wReserved2;
        ushort wReserved3;
        IntPtr p;
        int p2;

        private byte[] GetDataBytes()
        {
            byte[] ret = new byte[IntPtr.Size + sizeof(int)];
            if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                BitConverter.GetBytes(p.ToInt32()).CopyTo(ret, 0);
            else if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
                BitConverter.GetBytes(p.ToInt64()).CopyTo(ret, 0);
            BitConverter.GetBytes(p2).CopyTo(ret, IntPtr.Size);
            return ret;
        }

        sbyte cVal // CHAR cVal;
        {
            get { return (sbyte)GetDataBytes()[0]; }
        }

        short iVal // SHORT iVal;
        {
            get { return BitConverter.ToInt16(GetDataBytes(), 0); }
        }

        int lVal // LONG lVal;
        {
            get { return BitConverter.ToInt32(GetDataBytes(), 0); }
        }

        long hVal // LARGE_INTEGER hVal;
        {
            get { return BitConverter.ToInt64(GetDataBytes(), 0); }
        }

        float fltVal // FLOAT fltVal;
        {
            get { return BitConverter.ToSingle(GetDataBytes(), 0); }
        }

        public object Value
        {
            get
            {
                switch ((VarEnum)vt)
                {
                    case VarEnum.VT_I1:
                        return cVal;
                    //case VarEnum.VT_UI1:return bVal;
                    case VarEnum.VT_I2:
                        return iVal;
                    //case VarEnum.VT_UI2:  return uiVal;
                    case VarEnum.VT_I4:
                    case VarEnum.VT_INT:
                        return lVal;
                    case VarEnum.VT_UI4:
                    //case VarEnum.VT_UINT: return ulVal;
                    case VarEnum.VT_I8:
                        return hVal;
                    // case VarEnum.VT_UI8:  return uhVal;
                    case VarEnum.VT_R4:
                        return fltVal;
                    /*case VarEnum.VT_R8:   return dblVal;
                    case VarEnum.VT_BOOL: return boolVal;
                    case VarEnum.VT_ERROR:  return scode;
                    case VarEnum.VT_CY: return cyVal;
                    case VarEnum.VT_DATE: return date;*/
                    case VarEnum.VT_FILETIME: return DateTime.FromFileTime(hVal);
                    case VarEnum.VT_BSTR:
                        return Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(p);
                    case VarEnum.VT_BLOB:
                        byte[] blobData = new byte[lVal];
                        IntPtr pBlobData;
                        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                        {
                            pBlobData = new IntPtr(p2);
                        }
                        else if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
                        {
                            // In this case, we need to derive a pointer at offset 12,
                            // because the size of the blob is represented as a 4-byte int
                            // but the pointer is immediately after that.
                            pBlobData = new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt64(GetDataBytes(), sizeof(int)));
                        }
                        else
                            throw new NotSupportedException();
                        Marshal.Copy(pBlobData, blobData, 0, lVal);
                        return blobData;
                    case VarEnum.VT_LPSTR:
                        return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(p);
                    case VarEnum.VT_LPWSTR:
                        return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(p);
                    case VarEnum.VT_UNKNOWN:
                        return Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(p);
                    case VarEnum.VT_DISPATCH:
                        return p;
                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException("The type of this variable is not support ('" + vt.ToString() + "')");
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //*****************************************************


}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace com_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MMDeviceEnumerator devenum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();//Create CoClass
            IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)devenum;
            IMMDeviceCollection deviceCollection = null;
            IMMDevice dev = null;
            IPropertyStore propertyStore=null;

            try
            {                  
                object o = null;
                int hr;   

                hr = deviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow.eCapture, 0x0000000F /*DEVICE_STATEMASK_ALL*/, out o);               
                deviceCollection = o as IMMDeviceCollection;

                uint deviceCount = 0;
                hr = deviceCollection.GetCount(ref deviceCount);

                textBox1.Text = "";
                for (uint i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)//print all devices
                {
                    hr = deviceCollection.Item(i, out o);

                    dev = o as IMMDevice;

                    //get device name
                    hr = dev.OpenPropertyStore(0/*STGM_READ*/, out o);                    
                    propertyStore = o as IPropertyStore;

                    PropVariant friendlyName=new PropVariant();
                    hr = propertyStore.GetValue(Native.PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, out friendlyName);                     

                    //output data
                    textBox1.Text += "#" + (i + 1).ToString() + ": " + friendlyName.Value.ToString();
                    textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;


                    //clean up resources
                    if (dev != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dev); dev = null; }
                    if (propertyStore != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(propertyStore); propertyStore = null; }


                }
                textBox1.Select(0, 0);

            }
            finally
            {
                //clean up resources
                if (devenum != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(devenum);
                if (deviceEnumerator != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
                if (deviceCollection != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceCollection);
                if (dev != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dev);
                if (propertyStore != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(propertyStore);

            }            

        }
    }
}
```

---

**Дополнение**

Для получения WaveInID устройства, нужно получить Endpoint ID всех WaveIn-устройств и сравнить его с результатом `device.GetID`:

```
class DShow
{
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern uint waveInGetNumDevs();

        public const uint DRV_RESERVED = 0x0800;
        public const uint DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID   =   (DRV_RESERVED + 17);
        public const uint  DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEIDSIZE = (DRV_RESERVED + 18);
        public const uint DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACE = (DRV_RESERVED + 12);
        public const uint DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACESIZE = (DRV_RESERVED + 13);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "waveInMessage")]
        public static extern int waveInMessage1(uint hWaveIn, uint msg, 
            ref uint dw1, uint dw2);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "waveInMessage")]
        public static extern int waveInMessage2(uint hWaveIn, uint msg, 
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder dw1, uint dw2);

        public static uint GetWaveInID(string endpid)
        {
            uint num = DShow.waveInGetNumDevs();
            StringBuilder sb;
            uint size = 0;
            for (uint i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                size = 0;
                DShow.waveInMessage1(i, DShow.DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEIDSIZE, ref size, 0);

                sb = new StringBuilder((int)size + 10);
                DShow.waveInMessage2(i, DShow.DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID, sb, size);                
                if (sb.ToString() == endpid) return i;
            }
            throw new EntryPointNotFoundException(endpid+" device was not found!");
        }
}
```

---

**Дополнение 2**

Ну и объяснение первоначальной проблемы: обрезка Friendly name в DirectShow вызвана ограничением в Wave Audio API, который он внутренне использует в Windows 7. В структуре [WAVEINCAPS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743839(v=vs.85).aspx) поле под имя устройства имеет фиксированный размер в 32 байта. В Windows 10 видимо принцип работы изменили, так что эта структура не задействована. Также следует отметить, что Wave Audio API начиная с висты объявлен устаревшим, и новые приложения должны вместо него использовать соответствующие функции из Multimedia Device API, WASAPI, Windows Media Foundation или DirectShow.

Ссылки по теме:

[Windows Multimedia Device API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316556(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Описание понятия Endpoint ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd370837(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Взаимодействие с Wave Audio API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd370819(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: На строчке `hr = propertyStore.GetValue(Native.PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, out friendlyName);` даёт исключение `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Исключение из HRESULT: 0xE000020B'`.

Comment: @D .Stark - на каком-то одном устройстве, или на всех? Или у вас одно устройство?

Comment: Ну пока дак на одном (Windows 10). Не вижу смысла проверять на нескольких, если не работает уже..

Comment: @D.Stark я имею в виду устройство из deviceCollection. Если у вас их несколько, и падает на одном, нужно обработать исключение и идти дальше, так как это может быть проблема одного устройства. Попробуйте также EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow.eCapture, 0x0000000F...) заменить на EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow.eCapture, 0x00000001...)

Comment: Устройство в смысле одно.

Comment: Это у вас локальная проблема похоже (исключение). Либо с устройством, либо с драйвером что-то. У меня на 3 компьютерах с разными звуковыми адаптерами ничего такого не наблюдается. А исходная проблема - ограничение WaveAudio API. Надо фильтровать только DirectSound устройства, они нормально должны отображаться.

Comment: Я заменил значение и теперь всё работает. Сейчас я перепроверю под другим DirectX'ом.

Comment: Да. Под 11-ым теперь тоже работает.

Comment: Только я помню почему отказался от этого метода. Он перечисляет во-первых виртуальные устройства (т.е. в списке я виже 3 (+5 пустых строк (?)), а реально существует 1), а во-вторых `IPropertyStore` не позволяет извлечь `WaveInID` (в отличии от `IPropertyBag`, который извлекается через `IMoniker::BindToStorage`).

Comment: Т.е. вопрос теперь в том как получить этот `WaveInID` и отличить виртуальные устройства от реальных.

Comment: А вот исключение в коде - ваша ошибка. Я поменял объявления COM типов и всё работает так же при значении `DEVICE_STATEMASK_ALL`.

Comment: @D.Stark У меня при указании DEVICE_STATEMASK_ACTIVE показываются только реально подключенные устройства. Может просто у вас устройства не умеют детектировать присутствие кабеля. Что касается установления соответствия с WaveInId, то это делается с помощью сравнения Endpoint ID. вот тут описано, как это провернуть: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd370837(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы говорите о `IMMDevice::GetId`. При помощи его получим Endpoint ID. А как конвертировать его в WaveInID в статье я не нашёл.

Comment: @D.Stark в цикле вызвать waveInMessage для всех устройств, и сравнить полученный ID. Вот тут пример кода: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd370819(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Где я могу найти значение `DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEIDSIZE`? В функцию waveInMessage первым параметром передаётся `waveInID`, вторым - код запроса (`DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEIDSIZE`), третьим - ссылка на параметр принимающий значение размера Endpoint ID, четвёртым тут - 0. Ну а если говорить о получении самого `DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID`, последним параметром - размер из первого вызова. Третий параметр какой тип должен иметь? `out object`?

Comment: Константы вот здесь посмотрите: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e300b98-24cd-4ead-b92e-741f9e69eea4/how-do-i-get-the-unik-identifier-using-waveinmessage?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал так: `IntPtr size = IntPtr.Zero;
waveInMessage(i, DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACESIZE, ref size, IntPtr.Zero);

IntPtr id = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
waveInMessage(i, DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACE, ref id, size);
` (как показано в примере по ссылке), но приложение просто вылетает на втором вызове `waveInMessage`.

Comment: Ну там, кстати, и говорится об ошибке, которая возвращается при запросе на  `DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACESIZE`. У меня это ошибки не даёт (0).

Comment: @D.Stark Угу, там немного не то. Добавил в ответ код, посмотрите.

Comment: Больше спасибо.

Comment: Все актуальные API представлены здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd370805(v=vs.85).aspx. Верно ли, что перечисление устройств нужно выполнять с использованием MMDevice API, а запись аудио с WASAPI? В статье говорится о поддержке этих интерфейсов в Windows Vista и Windows Server 2008. Верно ли, что программы использующие эти API будут надёжно работать на Windows Vista/7/8/10 и Server 2008/2008 R2/2012/2012 R2/2016?

Comment: @D.Stark На самом деле, я немного напутал в ответе, DirectShow не был объявлен устаревшим. Вы можете использовать DirectShow для захвата звука, если вам так удобнее (проблема с длиной имени устройства, это единичный баг, который может MS еще поправят). Да, MMDevice API и WASAPI работают на всех системах после висты.

Comment: Хорошо. MMDevice ведь предоставляет только возможности получения информации об устройствах - запись/воспроизведение аудио не реализуется?

Comment: Не могли бы помочь с этим примером: https://pastebin.com/vC7dVWh3. На выходе полная несуразица. Взято отсюда: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370800(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @D.Stark Да, для получения информации + является отправной точкой для работы с другими API (через метод Activate можно получить соответствующие этому устройству интерфейсы из DirectShow или WASAPI)

Comment: @D.Stark Как будет время посмотрю. Можете задать новый вопрос, чтобы было удобнее. Но учтите, что WASAPI - сильно низкоуровневый интерфейс, он для особых случаев. Возможно будет проще через DirectShow в сочетании с SampleGrabber, или какую-нибудь стороннюю библиотеку.

Comment: _Как будет время посмотрю_  - хорошо, я подожду. _Возможно будет проще через DirectShow в сочетании с SampleGrabber, или какую-нибудь стороннюю библиотеку_ - важно обойтись без сторонних библиотек.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793697/wasapi-Запись-звука