# Использование Desktop Duplication API

Tags: c++, c++-cli, directx, direct3d

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

#include "D3D9.h"
#include <Wincodec.h>
#include <chrono>

#include <shellapi.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <Atlbase.h>
#include <comdef.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "D3D11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "D3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")

#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")

using namespace System;

#define EXIT(hr) { if (FAILED(hr)) \
                { Console::WriteLine("Error!"); \
                Console::ReadKey(); return -1; } }

HBITMAP ExtractBitmap(ID3D11Texture2D* d3dtex, ID3D11Device* pDevice) 
{
    HRESULT hr;

    HBITMAP hBitmapTexture = NULL;
    HGDIOBJ hBitmap;

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    ID3D11Texture2D* pNewTexture = NULL;

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC description;

    d3dtex->GetDesc(&desc);
    d3dtex->GetDesc(&description);

    description.BindFlags = 0;
    description.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;

    if (FAILED(pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&description, NULL, &pNewTexture)))
    {
        Console::WriteLine("CreateTexture2D failed!");
        return NULL;
    }

    ID3D11DeviceContext* ctx = NULL;
    pDevice->GetImmediateContext(&ctx);

    ctx->CopyResource(pNewTexture, d3dtex);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
    UINT subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
    ctx->Map(pNewTexture, subresource, D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &resource);

    // Copy from texture to bitmap buffer.
    uint8_t* sptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(resource.pData);
    uint8_t* dptr = new uint8_t[desc.Width*desc.Height * 4];

    for (size_t h = 0; h < desc.Height; ++h)
    {
        size_t msize = std::min<size_t>(desc.Width * 4, resource.RowPitch);
        memcpy_s(dptr, desc.Width * 4, sptr, msize);
        sptr += resource.RowPitch;
        dptr += desc.Width * 4;
    }

    dptr -= desc.Width*desc.Height * 4;

    // Swap BGR to RGB bitmap.
    uint32_t *dPtr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(dptr);
    for (size_t count = 0; count < desc.Width*desc.Height * 4; count += 4)
    {
        uint32_t t = *dPtr;
        uint32_t t1 = (t & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
        uint32_t t2 = (t & 0x000000ff) << 16;
        uint32_t t3 = (t & 0x0000ff00);
        uint32_t ta = (t & 0xFF000000);
        *(dPtr++) = t1 | t2 | t3 | ta;
    }

    hBitmapTexture = CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetDC(NULL), desc.Width, desc.Height);
    SetBitmapBits(hBitmapTexture, desc.Width*desc.Height * 4, dptr);

    return (HBITMAP)CopyImage(hBitmapTexture, IMAGE_BITMAP, desc.Width, desc.Height, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
}


int main(array<System::String^> ^args)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    // Supported feature levels.
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
    };

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL d3dFeatLvl;
    ID3D11Device* pDevice = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* pImmediateContext = nullptr;

    // Get device object.
    hr = D3D11CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL, 0, featureLevels,
        ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &pDevice,
        &d3dFeatLvl,
        &pImmediateContext);
    EXIT(hr);

    // Get DXGI device.
    IDXGIDevice* DxgiDevice = nullptr;
    hr = pDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&DxgiDevice));
    EXIT(hr);

    // Get DXGI adapter.
    IDXGIAdapter* DxgiAdapter = nullptr;
    hr = DxgiDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&DxgiAdapter));
    DxgiDevice->Release();
    DxgiDevice = nullptr;
    EXIT(hr);

    // Get DXGI output.
    IDXGIOutput* DxgiOutput = nullptr;
    hr = DxgiAdapter->EnumOutputs(0, &DxgiOutput);
    DxgiAdapter->Release();
    DxgiAdapter = nullptr;
    EXIT(hr);

    DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC OutputDesc;
    DxgiOutput->GetDesc(&OutputDesc);

    // Query interface for Output1.
    IDXGIOutput1* DxgiOutput1 = nullptr;
    hr = DxgiOutput->QueryInterface(__uuidof(DxgiOutput1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&DxgiOutput1));
    DxgiOutput->Release();
    DxgiOutput = nullptr;
    EXIT(hr);

    // Create desktop duplication.
    IDXGIOutputDuplication* DeskDupl = nullptr;
    hr = DxgiOutput1->DuplicateOutput(pDevice, &DeskDupl);
    DxgiOutput1->Release();
    DxgiOutput1 = nullptr;
    EXIT(hr);

    DXGI_OUTDUPL_DESC OutputDuplDesc;
    DeskDupl->GetDesc(&OutputDuplDesc);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ID3D11Texture2D* AcquiredDesktopImage = nullptr;

    IDXGIResource* DesktopResource = nullptr;
    DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO FrameInfo;

    // Get new frame.
    hr = DeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(500, &FrameInfo, &DesktopResource);
    EXIT(hr);

    // If still holding old frame, destroy it.
    if (AcquiredDesktopImage)
    {
        AcquiredDesktopImage->Release();
        AcquiredDesktopImage = nullptr;
    }

    // Query interface for IDXGIResource.
    hr = DesktopResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&AcquiredDesktopImage));
    DesktopResource->Release();
    DesktopResource = nullptr;
    EXIT(hr);

    HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)ExtractBitmap(AcquiredDesktopImage, pDevice);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    System::Drawing::Bitmap::FromHbitmap(IntPtr(hBmp))->Save("Screenshot.bmp");

    Console::WriteLine("END!");
    Console::ReadKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Привожу пример своего исходника по работе с Desktop Duplication API (на C++/CLI).
К сожалению, не могу добиться от него результата - картинка получается пустая.
Каким образом можно поправить этот код, чтобы он работал; +добавить цикл, чтобы можно было получать скрины не вызывая функцию целиком.

Comment: Ну вот гляньте сюда, и посмотрите что половина значений NULL
https://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/08/15/0002/2330/141594/94/23ea93a4b4.jpg

Comment: Ну проблема, я смотрю, начинается с `DxgiDevice`. Т.е. первой не работает строчка  `hr = pDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&DxgiDevice));` и, соответственно, всё за ней.

Comment: `pDevice` получен верно. Что-то неправильно в `QueryInterface` или параметрах вызова `D3D11CreateDevice`.

Comment: Ну, так теперь сюда вот пристально присмотритесь, вы вызвали метод Release, но потом, из nullptr пытаетесь что-то вызвать? `IDXGIAdapter* DxgiAdapter = nullptr;
    hr = DxgiDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&DxgiAdapter));
    DxgiDevice->Release();
    DxgiDevice = nullptr;
    EXIT(hr);

    // Get DXGI output.
    IDXGIOutput* DxgiOutput = nullptr;
    hr = DxgiAdapter->EnumOutputs(0, &DxgiOutput);`

Comment: Поставил точку останова сразу после `pDevice->QueryInterface` и увидел, что `DxgiDevice` не `NULL`. Продолжил выполнение: `DxgiDevice - 0x00000000 <NULL>`. А по вашему замечанию - ничего не вижу такого. Я убил `DxgiDevice`, а не `DxgiAdapter`, для которого потом вызываю `EnumOutputs`. Всё верно.

Comment: Хотя чё это я)) Да всё верно что под конец выполнения кода куча `NULL`. Я же всё это сам убиваю и зануляю. Сейчас решил проверить правильность получения `IDXGIOutputDuplication` и `DXGI_OUTDUPL_DESC` - они на момент вызова `AcquireNextFrame` не `NULL`. С частью инициализации и подготовки к захвату изображения всё в порядке же.

Comment: Теперь проверил весь код "пошагово" и убедился, что все переменные перед их использованием не пусты. Так что проблема в другом.

Comment: @Birdy Значит `AcquireNextFrame` просто возвращает пустое изображение, либо оно портится после `ExtractBitmap`. Я думаю, скорее первое, чем второе, а значит, либо упущен какой-то вызов, либо  где-то нужно другие параметры, флаги выставить.

Answer (score 1):

Подробный ответ дан [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/740eb02c-b29e-40a9-b3bd-ff0b0468a95a/desktop-duplication-api-?forum=fordesktopru&prof=required)

Суть в двух моментах:

1. Однократного вызова AcquireNextFrame недостаточно для получения изображения экрана, так как "Frame" - это необязательно изображение экрана, а совокупность некоторой информации о изменении состояния рабочего стола (среди которой, иногда, может быть и изображение экрана). Для получения изображения нужно циклически вызывать AcquireNextFrame и сохранять все полученные результаты.
2. Для корректного зацикливания нужно освободить Frame:

   ```
   IDXGIOutputDuplication* DeskDupl;
   //инициализация...

   DeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(5000, &FrameInfo, &DesktopResource);

   //работа с Frame...

   hr = DeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();//освобождаем Frame

   if (FAILED(hr))
   {
      //произошла ошибка
   }
   else
   {
      //можно получить следующий Frame
   }
   ```

Comment: О да. Точно. Это мой вопрос на msdn. Забыл, что там его оставил и не вернулся)

Comment: У меня есть ещё более продвинутое решение.

Comment: Мой вопрос на CyberForum: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-cli/thread2038484.html

Comment: если DDA вас не удовлетворяет по скорости, то вам остается только писать свой драйвер с прямым чтением из видеокарты (естественно, про cli и управляемый код можно забыть)

Comment: Почему вы решили, что DDA меня не удовлетворяет по скорости? 6-14 мс отличный результат. Меня не удовлетворяет время на преобразование ID3D11Texture2D в management Bitmap. Скорее всего, это мне и не нужно.

Comment: @D .Stark неверно понял ваше сообщение в теме по ссылке. Так-то да, должен быть способ без этого преобразования сохранить в файл.

Comment: @D .Stark А в чем у вас смысл последней строки в ExtractBitmap, которая вызывает CopyImage? Если ее выкинуть (возвращать сразу hBitmapTexture), время сокращается на ~10 мс, и все нормально работает.

Comment: Нет. Даже если выкинуть, сократиться не на много. Результат будет около 100 мс. Там, если вы посмотрите среди моих сообщений, есть разделение на 4 части всего содержимого функции, и вот соотношения интервалов: 50/20/70/70 мс - в среднем.

Comment: Самое быстрое: 1/20/50/30 <=> 101 мс

Comment: Что-то много. У меня 30-40 мс занимает ExtractBitmap. Вы хоть с оптимизацией компилируете?

Comment: Да. Всё равно 40 мс это много. Мне тогда вообще какой смысл DDA использовать?..

Comment: Хотел бы найти способ быстрого преобразования ID3D11Texture2D в management Bitmap, т.к. на удалённом компьютере мне нужно будет масштабировать изображение с использованием бикубической интерполяции (Emgu CV).

Comment: Максимум - это 10 мс!

Comment: По моему вы ставите нереальные задачи. Зачем сохранять скриншоты с частотой около 100 раз в секунду? Так или иначе, из DDA вы уже выжали все что можно. А оптимизация обработки текстур это уже материал для отдельной темы.

Comment: Да я вот об этом и говорю. Я не собираюсь ускорять DDA - это невозможно. Мне нужна быстрая обработка текстур. Задам отдельный вопрос.

Comment: А вот по-поводу частоты - мне их ещё надо в Bitmap преобразовать, сжать, зашифровать, отправить по сети, расшифровать, декомпресмировать и отобразить. На всё это не больше 60 мс быть должно. Так что, для начала нужно ускорить процесс обработки скринов.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718965/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-id3d11texture2d-%D0%B2-management-bitmap