# Быстрое преобразование ID3D11Texture2D в management Bitmap

Tags: c#, directx

Использую данный код: http://www.cleoag.ru/2013/05/12/directx-texture-hbitmap/ (part 2 + last comment).

К сожалению, его выполнение составляет 170+ мс.
Возможно ли такое сказочное чудо, чтобы ускорить его до 10 мс.
Нужен принципиально новый алгоритм?

Comment: Я так до конца и не понял, что вы пытаетесь сделать (на высоком уровне). Что-то вроде системы слежения за удаленным компьютером с отправкой изображения около 100 раз в секунду? Нужен ли вам вообще HBITMAP? Может лучше ваши текстуры скармливать через DirectShow какому-нибудь MotionJPEG-компрессору?

Comment: Да. Система слежения с отправкой изображение >25 раз в секунду. Нужен мне management Bitmap. Преобразование HBITMAP в management Bitmap через Bitmap.FromHbitmap слишком долгое. Скармливать MJPEG Direct2D текстуры? Зачем? Чтобы получить сжатые данные, которые потом можно очень быстро преобразовать в Bitmap?

Comment: Причём сжатие там вроде без потерь. Мне пригодно только такое.

Comment: Ну вы же по сети передавать будете сжатые данные. Зачем вам management bitmap, его возможности не позволяют ничего особенного (кроме сохранения в файл отдельных изображений). Да и не оптимизирован он под такие скорости.

Comment: Ой, не заметил что вы пересели на c#. На нем такое провернуть будет очено трудно...

Comment: Потому что я использую Emgu CV для масштабирования изображения. Он принимает только Bitmap. Да и вообще, действительно, решение должно быть под .net c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На c# не знаю, как это сделать. На с++/cli вот самое лучшее, чего удалось добиться:

```
System::Drawing::Bitmap ^ ExtractBitmap2(ID3D11Texture2D* d3dtex, ID3D11Device* pDevice) 
{
System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch ^ sw =gcnew System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch();
Int32 t1,t2;
HRESULT hr;

HBITMAP hBitmapTexture = NULL;
HGDIOBJ hBitmap;

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
ID3D11Texture2D* pNewTexture = NULL;

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC description;

sw->Start();
t1=sw->ElapsedMilliseconds;
d3dtex->GetDesc(&desc);
d3dtex->GetDesc(&description);

description.BindFlags = 0;
description.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
description.MiscFlags = 0;  

if (FAILED(pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&description, NULL, &pNewTexture)))
{
Console::WriteLine("CreateTexture2D failed!");
return nullptr;
}

ID3D11DeviceContext* ctx = NULL;
pDevice->GetImmediateContext(&ctx);

ctx->CopyResource(pNewTexture, d3dtex);

D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
UINT subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
ctx->Map(pNewTexture, subresource, D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &resource);

// Copy from texture to bitmap buffer.
uint8_t* sptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(resource.pData);
uint8_t* dptr = new uint8_t[desc.Width*desc.Height * 4];
UINT* p = NULL;
int i;
uint32_t x;

t2=sw->ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console::WriteLine("init time "+Convert::ToString(t2-t1));

t1=sw->ElapsedMilliseconds;
for (size_t h = 0; h < desc.Height; ++h)
{
size_t msize = std::min<size_t>(desc.Width * 4, resource.RowPitch);
memcpy_s(dptr, desc.Width * 4, sptr, msize);    
////
sptr += resource.RowPitch;
dptr += desc.Width * 4;
}

t2=sw->ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console::WriteLine("copy time "+Convert::ToString(t2-t1));

dptr -= desc.Width*desc.Height * 4;

t1=sw->ElapsedMilliseconds;

System::Drawing::Bitmap ^ bmp=gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(desc.Width,desc.Height,desc.Width*4,
System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format32bppRgb,(IntPtr)dptr);

t2=sw->ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console::WriteLine("convert time "+Convert::ToString(t2-t1));

return bmp;

}
```

Время: 15-17 мс на Intel Core i3

Comment: Да. C++/CLI тоже хорошо подойдёт.

Comment: Спасибо, приду домой, протестирую.

Comment: Мне не понятен этот кусок: 

    t1=sw->ElapsedMilliseconds;
    for (size_t h = 0; h (desc.Width * 4, resource.RowPitch);
        memcpy_s(dptr, desc.Width * 4, sptr, msize);    
        ////
        sptr += resource.RowPitch;
        dptr += desc.Width * 4;
    }

Comment: @D .Stark я походу облажался при копировании кода из студии на сайт, какой-то кусок выпал. Щас постараюсь поправить

Comment: Я так и понял))

Comment: @D .Stark вроде поправил

Comment: У меня работает со временем 15-40 мс. Intel Core i3 тоже.

Comment: Я думаю этот метод уже не ускорить. Не так ли?

Comment: @D .Stark Ну да, я больше не вижу как тут ускорить.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо за помощь.